# How to reduce image size from MB to KB?

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-uploading, image-resizing

I made a gallery application and stored more images in a SQL Server databse,
now I am getting images takes a lot of time.
So I want image uploading time MB to KB conversion (i.e.: 20KB, 30KB).
What shall I do? Help me, please.

My code is:

```
 private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(Admin.this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                imgadminview.setImageBitmap(bm);
                int bitmapByteCount= BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bm);
                System.out.print(bitmapByteCount);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
               long lengthbmp = byteArray.length;
                System.out.print(lengthbmp);

                if(lengthbmp<=1048576){
                    //KB or more
                    rxKb = lengthbmp/1024;
                    System.out.print(rxKb + " KBs");}
                else if(rxKb>=1024) {
                    //MB or more
                    rxMB = rxKb / 1024;
                    System.out.print(rxMB + " MBs");
                }else if(rxMB>=1024) {
                    //GB or more
                    long rxGB = rxMB / 1024;
                    System.out.print(rxGB + Long.toString(rxGB));
                }else {
                        //rxMB>1024
                    //rxKb > 1024
                }//rxBytes>=1024
                byte[] test=String.valueOf(rxKb).getBytes();
                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(test, Base64.DEFAULT);
                btarray = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, btarray.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        imgadminview.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
```

Comment: **1** - Storing images in a database is a **worst practice** (a,a, ***anti-pattern***). **2** - You can't squeeze an image 10 times without destroying it completely.

Comment: Thank you for your response, which way best..?

Comment: Like Instagram Images showing more than images and fast

Comment: you can try with the ThreadPoolExecutor concept.

Comment: this concept getting images fast from database..?

Comment: yes it downloads the image in the background based on the threads specified by threadpoolexecutor.

Comment: please can you post the example url or some coding.